# How long the cookie should be valid, what expiration to set for cookie

Tags: cookies

How long cookies should be stored for common cases e.g. for login forms, and generally how long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to easily be able to login you should set a long time. Its usually really annoying to have to input you password often.

If you inpect a cookie from facebook for example they expires in between a couple of months to a couple of years.